# Service Cloud Snap-ins SDK for Mobile Apps for Xamarin

Tags: service, xamarin.ios, sdk, cloud, salesforce-service-cloud

Salesforce provides **Service Cloud Snap-Ins SDK for IOS and Android**. One can use these SDKs to add Salesforce Knowledge, Case Management, Live Agent Chat, SOS and ServiceCore. My mobile app is developed with **Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android**.

Is it possible to use these SDKs with `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android`?